# Non-toxic reporter gene or other transgenic DNA integration verification method that does not kill/damage organism?

Tags: genetics

I have been thinking that I will just use EGFP to know whether my attempted transfection was successful, but I've been coming across some publications that over expression of GFP can cause cell death. I need to create a stable line of transgenic organisms that have rather delicate embryos, and the organisms themselves are mildly fluorescent, so I am concerned that I need to hit a sweet spot of fluorescence that may be difficult to achieve. Too much and my cells die and too little and its not detectable. Does anybody know of another method that doesn't require expression of fluorescent proteins and doesn't require me to kill my organisms for sequencing?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you investigated low copy expression vectors? If they are mildly fluorescent; which colour, and have you thought about RFP or another colour vs GFP?

Comment: beta gal, maybe? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi00O7ggN_8AhWVADQIHZTzAQEQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fam%2Fpii%2FS0141022921001435&usg=AOvVaw2eymUOIzNHuPITIS2yVzHp